# Vectorized numpy array manipulation without for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Let me try to explain the problem that I need to solve.

1.) I have a 1 by 34 vector of asset weights of a portfolio (they sum up to 1) (array: asset_allocation)

```
    asset_allocation = [0.03, 0.12, 0.04, ...., 0.09]
```

2.) I have a 34000 by 242 matrix of asset return scenarios (34 asset classes * 1000 scenarios, 241 columns with monthly periods of data, 1 additional column for a simulation identifier going from 1 to 1000 ) (array: asset_return_scenario)

```
    asset_return_scenario = [[1,1,..,2,2,...,1000,1000],[-0.03,...,0.015],...,[-0.12,...,0.04]]
```

What I need to do now is compute portfolio returns for every scenario and every period.

Hence I need to take the first 34 elements of the asset_return_scenario array (34 asset returns in period 1) and multiply it by the asset_allocation array and so on.

Therefore my final result (array: portfolio_returns) should be of the size 1000 by 241.

For now I have done this with two for loops:

One for-loop over the 1000 rows and one over the 241 columns. Below in the example code `ret_assets` just gives me a specific set of asset returns (34 by 241 matrix) out of the whole `asset_return_scenario` matrix for every iteration. This takes a lot of time, therefore I would like to avoid for-loops and solve my problem with numpy methods.

```
    for i in range(0,1000):
       ret_assets = asset_return_scenario[asset_return_scenario['SIMULATION'] == i+1][asset_return_scenario.columns[3:]]
       for j in range(0,241):
          if j == 0:
             portfolio_return[i,j] = 0
          else:
             portfolio_return[i,j] = ret_assets.iloc[:,j].dot(asset_allocation)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you make a small test case that people can play with, you might get some help.  The description and code sample are hard to follow.  Does the `iloc` imply that you are using `pandas`?  If so add that tag.